# Google indexed different web site on our IIS

Tags: iis, google-search, google-index

We've got 2 web site on our IIS (otokepenk.net and asansor.co). They are same mentality. And each web site has got different IP binding. We're using Godaddy DNS for all these sites. Actually, our problem is that google use indexs of the other site for the other one! I meant:

when you type **site:otokepenk.net** you will see some pages who aren't in otokepenk.net but in asansor.co with:

http://www.otokepenk.net/asansor-standartlari.aspx => actualy is a page on asansor(http://asansor.co/asansor-standartlari.aspx), but google indexed it with this domanin.

There is one more interesting thing; when I see the cache of this index, I saw link as asansor.co/asansor-standartlari.aspx !!

Thanks

Comment: You need to ensure both sites in IIS have proper Host Name entries to only allow requests for those entries to be served by the matching site. Also check your redirect settings to ensure site1 isnt serving content out of site2 etc.